# Rstudio run all codes when I press CTRL+ENTER

Tags: rstudio

I want to run only 169th code, I bring my cursor to the right of code and when I press Ctrl+enter it run from 138 to 174. How can I solve this?
There are in green colour also

I want only run 169th code within codes

Comment: This is difficult to anwser without seeing the code, can you provide us a way to reproduce it or at least see this code ? Please [see this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.